# Open Json url on webview Activity

Tags: java, android, json, webview, move

I have an activity that fetches content from a json URI (http://api.androidhive.info/feed/feed.json) and displays the contents in a list view.

The contents include images, URI of the post, description etc. Each content item has its own URI.

Instead of opening clicked URIs using a web browser, I would like instead to open it in *another* activity which has a webview.

Sorry for re-asking this question i have a problem.i got a source code from [http:// www.androidhive.info/2014/06/android-facebook-like-custom-listview-feed-using-volley](http://%20www.androidhive.info/2014/06/android-facebook-like-custom-listview-feed-using-volley) which works well and a great source code i have a problem trying to pass the click link to open within the app webview.

this is the JSON DATA

```
{
    "feed": [


        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "TIME",
            "image": "http://api.androidhive.info/feed/img/time_best.jpg",
            "status": "30 years of Cirque du Soleil's best photos",
            "profilePic": "http://api.androidhive.info/feed/img/time.png",
            "timeStamp": "1403375851930",
            "url": "http://ti.me/1qW8MLB"
        },
        {
            "id": 11,
            "name": "A. R. rahman",
            "image": "http://api.androidhive.info/feed/img/ar_bw.jpg",
            "status": "",
            "profilePic": "http://api.androidhive.info/feed/img/ar.jpg",
            "timeStamp": "1403375851930",
            "url": ""
        }
    ]
}
```

this is the MainActivity.java

```
package info.androidhive.listviewfeed;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

private ListView listView;

private FeedListAdapter listAdapter;

private List<FeedItem> feedItems;

private String URL_FEED = "http://api.androidhive.info/feed/feed.json";

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        feedItems = new ArrayList<FeedItem>();

        listAdapter = new FeedListAdapter(this, feedItems);
        listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

        // These two lines not needed,
        // just to get the look of facebook (changing background color & hiding the icon)
        getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#3b5998")));
        getActionBar().setIcon(
                   new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent)));

        // We first check for cached request
        Cache cache = AppController.getInstance().getRequestQueue().getCache();
        Entry entry = cache.get(URL_FEED);
        if (entry != null) {
            // fetch the data from cache
            try {
                String data = new String(entry.data, "UTF-8");
                try {
                    parseJsonFeed(new JSONObject(data));
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } else {
            // making fresh volley request and getting json
            JsonObjectRequest jsonReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Method.GET,
                    URL_FEED, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                            VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Response: " + response.toString());
                            if (response != null) {
                                parseJsonFeed(response);
                            }
                        }
                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                        }
                    });

            // Adding request to volley request queue
            AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonReq);
        }

    }

    /**
     * Parsing json reponse and passing the data to feed view list adapter
     * */
    private void parseJsonFeed(JSONObject response) {
        try {
            JSONArray feedArray = response.getJSONArray("feed");

            for (int i = 0; i < feedArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject feedObj = (JSONObject) feedArray.get(i);

                FeedItem item = new FeedItem();
                item.setId(feedObj.getInt("id"));
                item.setName(feedObj.getString("name"));

                // Image might be null sometimes
                String image = feedObj.isNull("image") ? null : feedObj
                        .getString("image");
                item.setImge(image);
                item.setStatus(feedObj.getString("status"));
                item.setProfilePic(feedObj.getString("profilePic"));
                item.setTimeStamp(feedObj.getString("timeStamp"));

                // url might be null sometimes
                String feedUrl = feedObj.isNull("url") ? null : feedObj
                        .getString("url");
                item.setUrl(feedUrl);

                feedItems.add(item);
            }

            // notify data changes to list adapater
            listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

and this is the webview.java i created when the links gotten from [http:// api.androidhive.info/feed/feed.json](http://%20api.androidhive.info/feed/feed.json) be passed and open in webview when clicked

```
public class webview extends Activity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.webview);
        String getStringFromEdittext = "https:// www.google.co.in"+      getIntent().getExtras().getString("text");
        WebView wb = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);

        wb.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        System.out.println("URL"+getStringFromEdittext);
        wb.loadUrl(getStringFromEdittext );
        wb.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                           Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                           startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });
}
}
```

Comment: Please format _all_ of your code as code.

Comment: what is you want to achieve? open in another activity or in same webview?

Comment: the MainActivity is not a webview , it is fetching data from json server and displaying it i want the url to be opened in another Activity containing webview

Comment: Do you still need an answer?

Comment: I really need the answer as urgent and fast as Obama jet

Comment: please can anyone help me with the answer to my question

Comment: can some one help me with the answer please

Comment: `I really need the answer as urgent and fast as Obama jet` - then perhaps you should pay someone to debug your code if that's so important

Comment: The code is working but when you click on any like it opens in android web browser instead of the webview i made for it

Answer (score 1):

This might not be exactly what you are looking for but this is how i did my own. this answer is kinda related to what you need bit not hundred percent what you need.

I understand that you want the link to open on webview rather than android web browser i took the libaty to restructure the above coding with the aid of the post http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-working-with-action-bar/

I repeat again this code might not be 100 percent of what you need and also its for mainly for people who want to use the above code for wordpress or website with url like **www.example.com/page.php?1d=10**

**this will be the MainActivity.java**
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
private ListView listView;
private FeedListAdapter listAdapter;
private List<FeedItem> feedItems;
private String URL_FEED = "http://api.androidhive.info/feed/feed.json";

// action bar
    private ActionBar actionBar;

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    feedItems = new ArrayList<FeedItem>();

    listAdapter = new FeedListAdapter(this, feedItems);
    listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

    actionBar = getActionBar();

    // Hide the action bar title
            actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

    // These two lines not needed,
    // just to get the look of facebook (changing background color & hiding the icon)
    getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#3b5998")));
    getActionBar().setIcon(
               new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent)));

    // We first check for cached request
    Cache cache = AppController.getInstance().getRequestQueue().getCache();
    Entry entry = cache.get(URL_FEED);
    if (entry != null) {
        // fetch the data from cache
        try {
            String data = new String(entry.data, "UTF-8");
            try {
                parseJsonFeed(new JSONObject(data));
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    } else {
        // making fresh volley request and getting json
        JsonObjectRequest jsonReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Method.GET,
                URL_FEED, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Response: " + response.toString());
                        if (response != null) {
                            parseJsonFeed(response);
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                    }
                });

        // Adding request to volley request queue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonReq);
    }

}

/**
 * Parsing json reponse and passing the data to feed view list adapter
 * */
private void parseJsonFeed(JSONObject response) {
    try {
        JSONArray feedArray = response.getJSONArray("feed");

        for (int i = 0; i < feedArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject feedObj = (JSONObject) feedArray.get(i);

            FeedItem item = new FeedItem();
            item.setId(feedObj.getInt("id"));
            item.setName(feedObj.getString("name"));

            // Image might be null sometimes
            String image = feedObj.isNull("image") ? null : feedObj
                    .getString("image");
            item.setImge(image);
            item.setStatus(feedObj.getString("status"));
            item.setProfilePic(feedObj.getString("profilePic"));
            item.setTimeStamp(feedObj.getString("timeStamp"));

            // url might be null sometimes
            String feedUrl = feedObj.isNull("url") ? null : feedObj
                    .getString("url");
            item.setUrl(feedUrl);
            feedItems.add(item);

            //Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, webview.class);
            //intent.putExtra("text", feedUrl.toString());
            //startActivity(intent);
        }

        // notify data changes to list adapater
        listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.activity_main_actions, menu);

    // Associate searchable configuration with the SearchView
    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search)
            .getActionView();
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager
            .getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

/**
 * On selecting action bar icons
 * */
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Take appropriate action for each action item click
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.action_search:
        // search action
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

}

for the webview side this is the full code

SearchResultsActivity.java

package info.androidhive.listviewfeed;

public class SearchResultsActivity extends Activity {

```
private TextView txtQuery;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_search_results);

    // get the action bar
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();

    // Enabling Back navigation on Action Bar icon
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    txtQuery = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtQuery);

    handleIntent(getIntent());
}

@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    setIntent(intent);
    handleIntent(intent);
}

/**
 * Handling intent data
 */
private void handleIntent(Intent intent) {
    if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        String query = "http://www.guruslodge.com/"+ intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);

        /**
         * Use this query to display search results like 
         * 1. Getting the data from SQLite and showing in listview 
         * 2. Making webrequest and displaying the data 
         * For now we just display the query only
         */
        txtQuery.setText("Search Query: " + query);

        WebView wb = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);

        wb.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        System.out.println("URL"+query);
        wb.loadUrl(query );
        wb.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        wb.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            public void onReceivedError(WebView webView, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
                try {
                    webView.stopLoading();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }

                if (webView.canGoBack()) {
                    webView.goBack();
                }

                webView.loadUrl("about:blank");
                AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(SearchResultsActivity.this).create();
                alertDialog.setTitle("Error");
                alertDialog.setMessage("Cannot connect to the Elitesbase Server. Check your internet connection and try again.");
                alertDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Try Again", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        finish();
                        startActivity(getIntent());
                    }
                });

                alertDialog.show();
                super.onReceivedError(webView, errorCode, description, failingUrl);
            }
        });

    }

}
```

}

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:name=".app.AppController"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
            android:value=".SearchResultsActivity" />
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <!-- Search results activity -->
    <activity android:name=".SearchResultsActivity"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.searchable"
            android:resource="@xml/searchable" />

    </activity>
 <activity
        android:name=".webview"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

        <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

        <data
            android:host="elitesbase.com"
            android:pathPrefix="/cgi-sys/"
            android:scheme="http" />
        <data
            android:host="www.elitesbase.com"
            android:pathPrefix="/cgi-sys/"
            android:scheme="http" />
    </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Hope this answer can help

Comment: the answer is not exactly what i need but its better than nothing